# RubyOnRails - Does not keep the selected language when I refresh the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, rails-i18n

In development mode all work fine. But not in production mode on heroku.

When I select a locale and I refresh the page, it displays language by default half the time and the language I selected otherwise. I do not know what to do. I tried to clear the cache with Rails.cache.clear command, but it does not work. I guess the problem is with the cache system. I'm new to ruby on rails. Someone would have an idea how to fix this?

to understand my problem, you can go to my website, select the French language and refresh the page several times. Once the page is in French. Another time in English.

https://releaseit.herokuapp.com/

my application_controller:

```
  before_action :set_locale
  def set_locale
    if params[:locale].in? %W(en fr)
      I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
  end
```

The config files are same as here: https://github.com/starterkits/rails4-starterkit/tree/master/config

Sorry for my english (I am french and i use google translator)

Comment: How did you configure the language preference? Can you add some code? It's impossible to tell what is going wrong now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know (or see) where do you pass locale in URL. As far as I know in order to use `params[:locale]` your URL should look like:

```
https://releaseit.herokuapp.com/fr/something
https://releaseit.herokuapp.com/en/something
https://releaseit.herokuapp.com/en
https://releaseit.herokuapp.com?locale=fr
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

What is more try my `set_locale` method:

```
  def set_locale    
    if params[:locale]
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    else
      I18n.locale = http_accept_language.compatible_language_from(
        I18n.available_locales
      )
    end
  end
```

`set_locale` method should be executed on **every** page reload to set proper locale each time.

It requires `http_accept_language` gem from: `https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language`

Check out also `route_translator` gem for creating routes with locale.

Comment: I searched a long time to solve my problem. I was convinced that I should call my set_locale function once for the site remains in the selected language. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Well I didn't mention this, but I'm happy that you figured it out based on my answer. I'll update it.